# Wait until the user touches the screen. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wait

After something happens I make a view appear with a label,

```
let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width: 100, height: 100))
myView.addSubview(lebel)
self.view.addSubview(myView)
myView.alpha = 0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        myView.alpha = 1
    })
```

Now I want you to wait until a tap is made on the screen, and then

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            muView.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { (bool) in
            myView.removeFromSuperview()
    })
```

How can I wait until I touch the screen?

Comment: Wait what? Do you have to do anything explicitly in wait? Otherwise a tap gesture recognizer could trigger that...

Comment: Look up how to use UITapGestureRecognizer() . It lets you a listener of a top to a view, and allows you to select a function to fire when that tap happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add  tapGesture to Your View

At `viewDidload`

```
 let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGesture(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

handleTapGesture

```
 @IBAction func handleTapGesture(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            muView.alpha = 0
           }, completion: { (bool) in
            myView.removeFromSuperview()
       })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to Abdelahad's answer, you should declare `let myView` as a `property` to use it within `@IBAction func handleTapGesture(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {}`. So, the new code is the following:

```
 @IBAction func handleTapGesture(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.myView.alpha = 0
       }, completion: { (bool) in
        self.myView.removeFromSuperview()
   })
}
```

Finally adding, I found your slight mistake in your code. `muView` is wrong and `myView` is correct.